# vi search copy paste search copy

Tags: search, vim, copy, vi, paste

I was just wondering if anyone could help out with how to do the following using vi.

I have a text file and it might contain something like

```
start of text file:
--something1.something2--
--anotherThing1.something2--
end of text file:
```

If I want to take this line and convert it by way of searching for anything matching the first occurrence of `[A-Za-z0-9]` copy that to the buffer then append it on the same line to before the first occurrent of --

```
start of text file:
--something1.something2.something1--
--anotherThing1.something2.anotherThing1--
end of text file:
```

Is there a single VI command to do this?

Cheers
Ben

Comment: So you want to copy the first word after '--' up to first '.' and append '.' and word found before the last '--'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:%s/--\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\).\(.*\)--/--\1.\2.\1--/gc
```

or without asking confirmation for every replace:

```
:%s/--\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\).\(.*\)--/--\1.\2.\1--/g
```

will produce:

```
--something1.something2.something1--
--anotherThing1.something2.anotherThing1--
```

from:

```
--something1.something2--
--anotherThing1.something2--
```

This is if you want to copy the first word after '--' up to first '.' and append '.' and word found before the last '--'.

Using vim.

**RE COMMENTS:**

Someone mentioned that it will not work when there are multiple words and so on.
I tested it on the following:

```
start of text file:
--something1.something2.something3.something4.something5.something6--
--anotherThing1.something2.anotherThing3.anotherThing4.anotherThing5--
end of text file:
```

after replace with the above expression:

```
start of text file:
--something1.something2.something3.something4.something5.something6.something1--
--anotherThing1.something2.anotherThing3.anotherThing4.anotherThing5.anotherThing1--
end of text file:
```

Comment: Remove the "c" from the end if you don't want to be asked to confirm each replacement.

Comment: The /g modifier to the regex is not necessary. Your regex does not work if there are multiple occurances of --text.text-- on one line.

Comment: what do you mean by --text.text-- ... do you have example that fails?

Comment: you guys are the bomb that is really great. I normally do the substitution a little differently.

:g/--\([A-Za-z0-9]*\).\(.*\)--/s//--\1.\2.\1--

Comment: really like the groups was not sure you could do it thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Holy crap, in the time it took me to login to post that answer, you posted it and already got a comment!

```
%s/--\(\w*\)\.\(.*\)--/--\1.\2.\1--/g
```

--ab1.cd2..yz99-- -> --ab1.cd2..yz99.ab1--

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
%s:\([A-Za-z0-9]\+\)\(\..\+\)--:\1\2.\1--:g
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on stefanB's solution but using negated character classes and the "very magic" setting, I arrive at the following substitution command:

```
:%s/\v--([^.]+)\.(.*)--/--\1.\2.\1--/
```

Depending on the exact requirements (what are allowed characters for "something1" and "anotherThing1") this might or might not be more correct.

One more thing to consider: all solutions posted so far assume that there is only one occurance of the "--text.someOtherText-- pattern per line. If this is not the case, the (.*) part of the pattern would have to be adjusted and the /g modifier is required.

Comment: I've actually tested with multiple segments like "--anotherThing1.something2.anotherThing1.anotherThing1.anotherThing1--" it will still add the first word before the last --